# Computing Gromov-Witten invariant of $4$ lines in $\mathbb{C}P^3$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

I'm trying to understand what the number of genus 0 curves through four lines in $\mathbb{C}P^3$ is i.e $Gr_{0,4}^{\mathbb{C}P^3, L}(PD(L),PD(L),PD(L),PD(L))$ where $L$ is the class of a line $\mathbb{C}P^1 \subset \mathbb{C}P^3$.

I can see that $\sum_{i=1}^{4} deg(PD(L)) = 16$ and  dim $\mathcal{M}_{0,4}(\mathbb{C}P^3,L) = 16$. Hence the Gromov-Witten invariants are not trivially zero.

However, I'm struggling to actually compute this number. Could someone help me with how to proceed in computing this?

Comment: Are you asking for the classical way to do this? This is quite elementary. The Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is a smooth quadric $\mathbb{G}$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$; the locus of lines meeting a given line $\ell$ is the intersection of $\mathbb{G}$ with the tangent hyperplane to $\ell$ in $\mathbb{G}$. Thus if your 4 lines are in general position you get the intersection of $\mathbb{G}$ with a line, that is 2 points.

Comment: If you want a slightly expanded version of what abx said, I wrote a blog post about this (with some pictures) back in 2012: jde27.uk/blog/lines-through-four-lines.html

Comment: Thank you very much! The blog post helped a lot.